# jFreeChart: Possible to combine StatisticalBarRenderer and LayeredBarRenderer?

Tags: jfreechart

I want to create a chart that consists of couples of two bars.
one of them a regular bar, the second one is layered and has a deviation.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
private static JFreeChart createStatisticalBarChart(DefaultStatisticalCategoryDataset dataset, String chartTitle, String domainAxisLabel, String rangeAxisLabel, List<String> sunndayMap) {

    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(domainAxisLabel);
    ValueAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(rangeAxisLabel);
    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new StatisticalBarRenderer();

    CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);


    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(chartTitle,
            new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10),
            plot,
            true);
```

My dataset has mean+standarddeviatin records with every second record's deviation being "0", so that no range indicators will be displayed.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small negative value in [`setItemMargin()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html#setItemMargin%28double%29) to achieve an overlap, for example

```
renderer.setItemMargin(-0.10f);
```

It appears that [standard deviation lines](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StatisticalBarRenderer.html#line.504) are *not* drawn if the `getStdDevValue()` method returns `null`. You might try that value instead of "0".